# Alternating colors based on row header change

Tags: google-sheets

I want my spreadsheet to automatically generate alternating colors based on row header change, like the image below.

Ideally without creating auxiliary columns or macro/scripts (which I can create myself but don't want to). The length of the table is variable and the table is dynamic.

[image: example]

I've tried to create some magic logic with conditional formatting, but while I can create logic that identifies a row header changes (using the `=(A3=A2)` logic,  I could not find a way to identify to color of the previous row. So the answer to the question on how to (using formulas and no script) identify the background color of a determined cell could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using formulas and no scripts: it does require two helper columns the second of which you can easily apply the conditional formatting of the colors of your choosing:

Helper Column 1 (A1:A10=A2:A11 should be replaced with the cells you are looking for change)

```
=arrayformula({n(whatthefoxsay());IF(A1:A10=A2:A11,n(whatthefoxsay()),1)})
```

Helper Column 2 (replace C1:C11 with the helper column 1 and voila the fox will make your conditional formatting very simple)

```
=lambda(fox,arrayformula(mod(MMULT(IF(ROW(fox)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(fox))=TRUE,1,0),fox),2)))(C1:C11)
```

I wasn't able to accomplish this without helper columns, I came up with a few solutions that used circular reference and other horrible ideas but the performance was so bad it wasn't even worth mentioning.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I've also learned about google sheets easter eggs that I was not aware of!

Comment: btw, i've slightly extended the formulas to ```=arrayformula({n(whatthefoxsay());IF(A1=A2:A,n(whatthefoxsay()),1)})``` and ```=lambda(fox,arrayformula(mod(MMULT(IF(ROW(fox)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(fox))=TRUE,1,0),fox),2)))(C1:C)``` so that the solution also works when I populate the table with more data

Comment: I am assuming also that I can't make all items of the first column except the first appearance transparent, because only one conditional formatting rule can apply to a cell, right?

Comment: @Oren cells can have multiple conditional formats but the one you order to the top is executed last.

Comment: @Oren you can use `array_constrain` to make it so it doesn't overflow with your new reference.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two formulas (*without creating auxiliary columns or macro/scripts*):

for the `green` color:

```
=isodd(code($A1))
```

for the `yellow` color:

```
=iseven(code($A1))
```

[image: cf]

Comment: Thanks, that's ingenious! But unfortunately the 'A, B, Cs' were just examples, and the actual categories are not in any particular "code()" order

Comment: If you want to have correct answers, please provide us with correct data

Comment: @Daniele I'll give you a thumbs up anyway, definitely a great idea.

Comment: @CodeCamper
 thank you